# Will my server reboot itself if the memory fills up?

Tags: server, ram

I just got a VDS, all said and done with my website, forums and email server set up along with my Teamspeak server. My memory usage is at 60% when it boots and grows to 70% after about 3 hours of running.  I'm just curious on what will happen if the memory fills up and would it notify me in some way if it did?

Answer (score 2):

In case your machine runs out of memory for the processes, the kernel's [Out-of-Memory-killer](http://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer) (also known as OOM killer) kicks in.

It will hard-kill processes based on a certain algorithm, by providing scores. Your syslog/dmesg will then list entries like:

```
[11686.043641] Out of memory: Kill process 2603 (flasherav) score 761 or sacrifice child
[11686.043647] Killed process 2603 (flasherav) total-vm:1498536kB, anon-rss:721784kB, file-rss:4228kB
```

While the processes are killed, you'll have to install monitoring on the server to get notified, such as [logcheck [image: Install logcheck]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/logcheck).

For services (daemons) you can tell Upstart you [respawn](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/wiki/Stanzas#respawn) the process for you. You can also set adjustments for the OOM-score in Upstart: [How to set OOM killer adjustments for daemons permanently?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/58872/23363)